# Getting a part of a dynamic string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following dynamic string:

```
[TITLE|prefix=a] [STORENAME|prefix=s|suffix=s] [DYNAMIC|limit=10|random=0|reverse=0]
```

And I would like to get the value **a** from [TITLE|prefix=**a**] and the value **s** from [STORENAME|prefix=s|suffix=**s**].

To get the prefix value of TITLE, I have tried it with `result.match(/prefix=*\||\]/)` but I'm not getting what I need.

Comment: My current solution is `result.match(/(TITLE)*(prefix=)(.+?)(\||\])/)`. Feel free to add an answer if you have a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start by matching `[` and uppercase chars A-Z. then match `|prefix` followed by capturing in a group what you want to keep.

Then optionally match `|suffix` and use another group to capture what you want to keep.

```
\[[A-Z]+\|(prefix=)([^\]|]+)(?:\|(suffix=)([^\]|]+))?]
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IjxK5K/1)

```js
const regex = /\[[A-Z]+\|(prefix=)([^\]|]+)(?:\|(suffix=)([^\]|]+))?]/g;
const str = `[TITLE|prefix=a] [STORENAME|prefix=s|suffix=s] [DYNAMIC|limit=10|random=0|reverse=0]`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  console.log(`key: ${m[1]}`)
  console.log(`value: ${m[2]}`)
  if (m[3] !== undefined) {
    console.log(`key: ${m[3]}`)
    console.log(`value: ${m[4]}`)
  }
}
```

---

If `[TITLE` has to be on the left, you might also use a positive lookbehind with an infinite quantifier to get the matches:

```
(?<=\[TITLE\|.*)(prefix=|suffix=)([^|\]*])
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/I67pvH/1)

```js
const regex = /(?<=\[TITLE\|.*)(prefix=|suffix=)([^|\]*])/g;
const str = `[TITLE|prefix=a] [STORENAME|prefix=s|suffix=s] [DYNAMIC|limit=10|random=0|reverse=0]`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  console.log(`key: ${m[1]}`)
  console.log(`value: ${m[2]}`)
}
```

Comment: If I use `result.match(/\[[A-Z]+\|prefix=([^\]|]+)(?:\|suffix=([^\]|]+))?]/)[1]`, I'll get the prefix of TITLE but how I do get the prefix of STORENAME?

Comment: @Proseller I have updated both patterns to get 2 capturing groups, the first with the key name and the second with the value name

Answer (score 1):

Try below:

```
(?<=TITLE\|prefix=)[\w]+|(?<=[\w]+\|suffix=)[\w]+
```

Explanation:

- TITLE|prefix= --> Will search for text "TITLE|prefix="
- ?<= --> will deselect it
- (?<=[\w]+|suffix=) --> Similarly, will select "suffix=" and anything before it, and will deselect it
- [\w]+ --> will select word after "TITLE|prefix=" and "suffix="

Answer (score 1):

You could try following regex.

```
(?<=prefix=).*?(?=]|\|)
```

**Details**:

- `(?<=prefix=)`: Lookbehind - matches string after the characters `prefix=`
- `.*?`: matches any characters as few as possible
- `(?=]|\|)`: gets any characters until `]` or `|`

I also tried to run code on javascript.

```js
var string = "[TITLE|prefix=a] [STORENAME|prefix=s|suffix=s] [DYNAMIC|limit=10|random=0|reverse=0]";
    
var res = string.match(/(?<=prefix=).*?(?=]|\|)/g);
console.log(res);
```